# probability and expectation of random variable coin

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

If the probability that head is 1/2 and the probability that the back is 1/2, coin is repeatedly throws
 twice.

w1=(H,H)

w2=(T,H),

w3 = (H,T),

w4= (T,T),

The sample space is Ω = {w1,w2,w3,w4}

The random variable X: Ω →
 R and the random variable Y: Ω → R for all w∈Ω, the probability P is P ({w)) = ¼ and is defined

X (w) = 0 for w∈{w1,w3}

X(w)=1,  for w ∈ {w2, w4}

Y (w) =0, for w∈{w1,w2}

Y(w)=1, for w∈{w3,w4}

Further, the random variable
 Z: Ω → R is defined by Z (ω) = max {X (w), Y (w)} with respect to ωEΩ.

1. Show P (X = i, Z = k) for
   i, k = 0,1,2
2. Show P (Z = k) for k =
   0,1.

   3. Find E [X] and E [Z].
   4. Find E [XZ].
3. Find E[X | Z = 1].
4. Find the variance V of
   V[X] and the variance V[Z]
5. Find the correlation coefficient
   p (X, Z) of X and Z

1.P(X=0,Z=0)=1/4　
P(X=0,Z=1) =1/3 
P(X=1,z=1) =2/3 
2.P(Z=0)=1/4 
 
P(Z=1) = 12/16 
3.E[X]=0 + 1.P(X=1)=P{w2,w4}=1.2/4=1/2 
 E[Z]= E[Z=0]+E[Z=1]=1.P(Z=0) = 12/36 
4. im not sure
5.$E[X|Z=1]= 1.p(1,1)/p_z(1)=1 + 0= \frac{2}{3}$ 
6.V[X]=E[X^2]-(E[x])2 
E[X^2]=0 + 1.P(X=1)=P{w2,w4}=1.2/4=1/2 
1\2-1\4=3\4

as for variance im not quite sure whether E[X} is right or not, am i right so far ? how can i findE[XZ] too?

Comment: Just use more natural language... $X$ is the indicator random variable which equals $1$ if the first coin is a head and $0$ otherwise while $Y$ is the indicator random variable which equals $1$ if the second coin is a head and $0$ otherwise.  Meanwhile $Z$ is the indicator random variable which equals $1$ if at least one of the coins shows a head and $0$ otherwise when both coins show tails.

Comment: As $X,Y,Z$ are indicator random variables (random variables who only take values $0$ or $1$), it follows that $E[X]$ is very simply equal to $Pr(X=1)$ which is $\frac{1}{2}$.  Meanwhile $E[Z]=Pr(Z=1)=\frac{3}{4}$.  As for $E[XZ]$, this too is simple since they are indicator random variables, you will have $E[XZ]=Pr(X=1,Z=1)$ which you should be able to see is simply $Pr(X=1)$

Comment: @JMoravitz thankyou so much!! So for E[XZ] it just need to multiply value of X times Z? As 0.1,1.0,0.0,1.1 ? So only 1.1=1 left? If there is for example non zero value, just have to sum it?

Comment: @JMoravitz  for this problem when you find E[X], when find probability X=1, p(w2,w4) =1/4+1/4=1/2 is this independent so you sum up the probability?

Comment: Do not confuse the words *independent* with *mutually exclusive*.  They mean totally different things.  When finding the probability that $X=1$, you can add up the respective probabilities of each atomic outcome which comprise the event since they are *mutually exclusive* to get the overall probability.

Comment: For $E[XZ]$, yes, you can ignore all terms which equate to zero, which as mentioned before leaves you with just $Pr(X=1,Z=1)$ which as mentioned before since the event where $X=1$ is a subevent of the event where $Z=1$ this simplifies to just $Pr(X=1)$.  Rephrased, if we know that the first coin is a head and we know that at least one coin is a head, this happens if and only if the first coin is a head.

Comment: Thankyou i find a little bit hard to differentiate independent and mutually exclusive and also for E[Z] = 1.P( Z=1 )which is when X,Y=(0,1),(1,0),(1,1) , Z =1 , for each there are 4 pair of w1,w2,w3,w4 so 4x3=12 / 2^4=16 (possibility of pair ) =3/4 , am i right?

Comment: "*for each there are 4 pair of...*"  No.  The event $Z=1$ is equal to the event $\{w_1, w_2, w_3\}$.  There are only four outcomes in total in our sample space.  We only ever need to express things as a fraction with $4$ as the denominator, never anything larger than that.  It is $\frac{3}{4}$, yes, but you went off on a tangent with thinking we needed to talk about $w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4$ again when really we didn't, or if we did want to that we already had been talking about them all along just with different names.

Answer (score 1):

**Comment:** @JMoravitz has given you excellent guidance.
Here is a simulation in R statistical software that gives
some answers (accurate to 2 or 3 places), along with some formulas you may have seen in your course (or may see soon).

```
set.seed(611)
x = rbinom(10^6, 1, .5);  y = rbinom(10^6, 1, .5)
z = pmax(x,y)
mean(x); mean(z); mean(x*z)
[1] 0.500266   # aprx E(X) = 1/2
[1] 0.750259   # aprx E(Z) = 3/4
[1] 0.500266   # aprx E(XZ) = 1/2

mean(x[z==1])
[1] 0.6667911  # aprx E(X|Z=1) = 2/3

mean(z^2)
[1] 0.750259   # note E(Z) = E(Z^2): WHY?
mean(z^2) - mean(z)^2
[1] 0.1873704
var(x); var(z)
[1] 0.2500002
[1] 0.1873706

mean(x*z) - mean(x)*mean(z)
[1] 0.1249369
cov(x,z);  cov(x,z)/(sd(x)*sd(z))
[1] 0.1249371
[1] 0.5772585
cor(x,z)
[1] 0.5772585
```

Because $$Cov(X,Z) = E[(X-E(X))(Z-E(Z)) \\= E(XZ) - E(X)E(Z),$$ the simulation approximates $Cov(X,Z)$ in two different ways (using the R function `cov` and using the formula).

Also, by definition,
$$\rho_{{}_{X,Z}} = Cor(X,Z) = \frac{Cov(X,Z)}{SD(X)SD(Z)},$$
which is approximated in two ways.

Comment: Thankyou so much i havent learn R language, but why Rbinom has to be 10^6? And what is seed(611)? And how you translate there is 4 event such as w1,w2,w3,w4 to the program(?) i mean in the program why you only use binom with n=1 and p=0.5?

Comment: @fiksx The seed is just there so that even though this is a "random" simulation we can ensure that we get the exact same results as one another.  Think of it as though we both shuffled our decks of cards in the exact same way.  As for the $10^6$, that was arbitrarily chosen.  We performed our experiment a "large number of times" ($10^6$ times to be precise) so that we could estimate the true probabilities.  There is nothing special about $10^6$ other than it is an easy "large" number to write and think about.